# Splitting up a string and passing it to a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having some trouble trying to pass string objects to a function. In the query string of the url I pass fields which is a comma delimited string containing the attributes of interest.

I put the names of those attributes in the fields array. However now I am having trouble passing that information to a function.

In the code below the query.pluck('id', 'name') works, the query.pick( fieldString ) does not.

I am stuck on this one, how can I pass the attribute names in the fields array to the function so it will work?

Please advice.

```
 var log = require('logule').init(module,'query');
 var url = require('url');

 module.exports = {

   build : function(req, entity, callback) {
     var isCollection;
     isCollection = req.params.id? false: true;
     var query = req.rethink.table(entity);
     parsedUrl = url.parse(req.url, true);

     console.log(isCollection);

     if (parsedUrl.query.fields) {
       var fields = parsedUrl.query.fields.split(',');
       var total = fields.length;

       fieldString = fields[0]; 
       for (var i = 1; i < total; i++) {
         fieldString += ', ' + fields[i];
       }

       if (isCollection) {
         var query = query.pluck('id', 'name');      
       } else {
         var query = query.get(req.params.id).pick( fieldString );
       }
     }

     return callback(null, query);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put fields in a string, just use

```
var query = query.get(req.params.id).pick.apply(this,fields);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either: Object #<Object> has no method 'compile'

Comment: it probably means you have problems in other parts of the code. 'compile' doesn't sound like a Javascript method. Try calling the pick method with hardcoded values which you know should NOT fail.. and read more about `apply` here,  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: I'm using the rethinkdb npm (rethinkdb@1.2.6-0) you mean to say that module is broken?

Comment: no it doesn't mean its broken, I looked at the documentation and it seems that all functions use .run() method, http://www.rethinkdb.com/api/#js:document_manipulation-pick maybe the error is happening inside the callback function

Comment: Well it looks like it: {"message":"Object #<Object> has no method 'compile'","name":"TypeError","stack":"TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'compile'\n    at R.compile (/opt/shihai/node_modules/rethinkdb/rethinkdb.js:89:143)\n    at R.na.B (/opt/shihai/node_modules/rethinkdb/rethinkdb.js:15:437)\n    at zc.Y.ma (/opt/shihai/node_modules/rethinkdb/rethinkdb.js:152:354)\n    at R.r.ma (/opt/shihai/node_modules/rethinkdb/rethinkdb.js:15:128)\n

Comment: Is there a way around this?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the "apply" function with the function name, and an array of parameters (fields in your case)

var query = query.get(req.params.id).apply('pick', fields);

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, this is what I get: TypeError: Object [object Function] has no method 'apply'\n